# Grid search for SVC : IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, grid-search, svc

I'm trying to use `GridSearchCV` to find the best params for `SVC`.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import svm, grid_search
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = [
        {'C': [1,5,10,100]},
        ]
algo = SVC(kernel="poly",  degree=5, coef0=2)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(algo, param_grid, cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(grid_search.best_params_) #line 162
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "main.py", line 162, in <module>
  IndexError: too many indices for array
```

When I don't use `GridSearchCV` it works:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import svm, grid_search
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

algo = SVC(kernel="poly", C=1, degree=5, coef0=2)
algo.fit(X_train, y_train)
predict_test = algo.predict(X_test)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, predict_test)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
print(rmse)
```

I get a score.

Comment: What is the output of `y_train.shape`?

Comment: The output of y_train.shape is (892, 1), and the output of X_train.shape is (892, 14)

Comment: Use `y_train = y_train.reshape(892,)` before `grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)`. Any error now?

Comment: Yeah!! thanks! What was the problem? why (892,) is valid (without the other attribute), and (892,1) doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GridSearchCV.fit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.fit) accepts target values as an array-like `y` of shape `[n_samples]` or `[n_samples, n_output]`.

In your case, `(892,)`. Therefore, reshape `y_train`:

```
y_train = y_train.reshape(892,)
```